# Remove an item from the middle of a Queue?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

Is it possible to remove an item and have the queue for multithreading reorder itself in Python?

I have users queued up in a Queue, but when it's time to process the user and if the user disconnects, that will raise an issue.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Cannot you just mark the disconnected element as dead and skip it later instead of removing it on the fly?

Comment: Yeah.. I also got the idea after I posted the question, but I didn't have internet until now..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Queue` objects do not provide random access.  However, you can achieve the same goal by retaining references to the objects in the queue somewhere else and marking them stale.  When the object is read from the queue, the consumer can check to see if the object is stale, and if it is, throw it away and read again.

You may also find value in the `PriorityQueue` class, where you put `(priority, message)` instead of just `message` onto the queue, and the data with the lowest `priority` value is always the next one read from the queue.  This by itself won't solve your issue, but it may give you a way to prioritize the oldest request or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible. You can remove a specific item by accessing the queue element.
remove is a method in Queue.queue

```
>>> from queue import Queue
>>> f = Queue(3)
>>> f.put(4)
>>> f.put(3)
>>> f.put(2)
>>> f.queue
deque([4,3,2])
>>> f.queue.__dir
['__new__', '__repr__', '__hash__', '__getattribute__', '__lt__', '__le__', '__eq__', '__ne__', '__gt__', '__ge__', '__iter__', '__init__', '__len__', '__add__', '__mul__', '__rmul__', '__getitem__', '__setitem__', '__delitem__', '__contains__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', 'append', 'appendleft', 'clear', '__copy__', 'copy', 'count', 'extend', 'extendleft', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'popleft', '__reduce__', 'remove', '__reversed__', 'reverse', 'rotate', '__sizeof__', '__class_getitem__', 'maxlen', '__doc__', '__str__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__', '__reduce_ex__', '__getstate__', '__subclasshook__', '__init_subclass__', '__format__', '__dir__', '__class__']
>>> f.queue.remove(3)
>>> f.queue
deque([4,2])
```

Comment: This accesses undocumented implementation details of `queue.Queue`, as well as breaking the synchronization mechanisms the class uses, leading to potential exceptions or deadlock.

Comment: can you explain a little more because I think deque is a base class of Queue so accessing the base should be fine?

Comment: That is not how base classes work. `f.queue` is an attribute, and not a documented one. If `deque` was a base class of `Queue`, then `isinstance(f, collections.deque)` would report `True`, but it instead returns `False`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).